# Can a route be overwritten from the camel context while being executed？

Tags: apache-camel

I have a question regarding route management in Apache Camel. It seems to me that it should be handled, but I'm going to fire my question anyway.

If I have RouteA registered in the Camel Context and I execute it. While the route is being executed, another route with the same route id overwrites the original one (let's call it RouteA'). What will happen to the execution of the RouteA? What kind of behavior will I see?

I can imagine one of the following 3 cases:

1. RouteA Request --> Back end --> RouteA' overwrites RouteA -->
   RouteA Response
2. RouteA Request --> Back end --> RouteA' overwrites RouteA -->
   RouteA' Response
3. RouteA Request --> Back end --> RouteA' overwrites RouteA -->
   Exception

Thank you!

**Found my answer**

when you add a route with the same routeId, it will attempt to do:

2. stopRoute(routeId)
3. Then apply the graceful shutdown strategy.
4. removeRoute(routeId)
5. After applying the algorithm above that it will add the new route with the same routeId

I was essentially trying to understand what was the shutdown strategy in camel, which is explained in details in the source code under DefaultShutdownStrategy.java see:
https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/3c0b7d0367c10379bbb09a0d0bb56197885b5a51/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/DefaultShutdownStrategy.java#L85

Comment: How do you mean overwrite the original one? In what way?

Comment: So I guess i am attempting to update a route inside the camel context ==>

context.addRoutes(createDynamicRoute("RouteIdA", 
"direct:in", "mock:out-endpoint")); 
// given that the route above is still executing ==> 
context.addRoutes(redirectTrafficToDifferentEndpoint("RouteIdA", 
"mock:new-out-endpoint"));

Comment: You have to stop and start the route to overwrite it anyway and so to stop a route it has to complete the in-flight message process.. precisely you have can only overwrite after completion of the in-flight message processing .

Comment: What is your use case for such a complex scenario? Usually try to keep the route setup simple and let each route do one thing.